# WPF - Run an async Task with DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a small application that checks some system status and display it details.
I have the following code which is working. But I want to make sure it's optimal:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    // Dictionary to hold info
    Dictionary<string, int> dataHolder = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"status_code", "" },
        {"memory", "" },
        {"process", "" }
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartBtn.IsEnabled = false;

        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(updateUI);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();  
    }

    private async void updateUI(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        await loadInfo();
        StartBtn.IsEnabled = true;

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dataHolder)
        {
            // Display in the UI
        }
    }

    private async Task loadInfo()
    {
        int page = 1;
        var keys = new List<string>(dataHolder.Keys);            
        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            dataHolder[key] = "";
            //await asyncCall(key, page);
        }

        // Better asynchronously and in parallel
        await Task.WhenAll(keys.Select(key => asyncCall(key, page)));
    }

    private async Task asyncCall(string key, int page)
    {
        var htClient = new HttpClient();
        // code to retrieve data...
    }
}
```

So as I said before, this code is working but I read somewhere that having an `async void` method is not good practice as in `private async void updateUI(object source, EventArgs e)`. I could change it to `private async Task updateUI(object source, EventArgs e)` but then I would not be able to do `dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(await updateUI);`

Also how to start counting (Timer) only after the previous process is done?

Thank you

**EDIT:** I am using the `DispatcherTimer` because I want the application to retrieve the status information and update the UI every 5 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to code review, I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async void should be avoided, but they are acceptable when in an EventHandler so it's fine.

Why are you copying the keys of the dictionary into a list? Do you want a snapshot at a random point in time?

If you have potentially race conditions, I would change the Dictionary to a ConcurrentDictionary.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    // Dictionary to hold info
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _dataHolder = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"status_code", "" },
        {"memory", "" },
        {"process", "" }
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void StartBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartBtn.IsEnabled = false;

        while (true) // Your exit condition instead of the true.
        {
            await LoadInfo();

            foreach (var entry in _dataHolder)
            {
                // Display in the UI
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            //StartBtn.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadInfo()
    {
        const int page = 1;

        var keys = new List<string>(_dataHolder.Keys);

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            _dataHolder[key] = "";
            //await asyncCall(key, page);
        }

        // Better asynchronously and in parallel
        await Task.WhenAll(keys.Select(key => AsyncCall(key, page)));
    }

    private static async Task AsyncCall(string key, int page)
    {
        var htClient = new HttpClient();
        // code to retrieve data...
    }
```

Comment: I want the app to update the status information every 5 minutes.

Comment: If you click on the start button again, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: When the application is launched, nothing happens (UI is empty). Then when you click on start button, it updates the information immediately then 5 minutes later, it refreshes and again 5 min, a new refresh and so on

Comment: Why were you enabling the start button again?

Comment: This is just the first part. Eventually I want the user to enter a parameter in a textbox and launch the cycle of status check. But then he can change the parameter and start over.